# Remove rows where value in one column equals value in another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to figure out how to remove rows from a pandas dataframe in which two specified columns have the same value across a row.

For example, in the below examples I would like to remove the rows which have duplicate values in the columns 2 and 4.

For example:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
  Pat     123     John    456
  Pat     123     John    345 
  Jimmy   678     Mary    678 
  Larry   678     James   983
```

Would turn into:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
  Pat     123     John    456 
  Pat     123     John    345
  Larry   678     James   983
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951558/remove-rows-that-two-columns-have-the-same-values-by-pandas)

Comment: @pygo More variety of answers here, have marked that as dupe of this instead.

Comment: @coldspeed, How could that be marked as duplicate as that being the old post , However, this  is necent one to that, i'm afraid about the correct procedure of doing duplicate.

Comment: @pygo I usually refer people to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101#comment94216191_53645882) I made on another post of mine. TLDR; closure is based on post quality, not age.

Comment: Okay, it make sense, thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `Series.ne` (`!=`)

```
df[df['Column2'] != df['Column4']]

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

Or, using `operator.ne`:

```
df[operator.ne(df['Column2'], df['Column4'])]

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

Compare the two; get a mask, then filter.

With `loc`, we can also supply a callback (suggested by @W-B!).

```
df.loc[lambda x : x['Column2'] != x['Column4']]

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

---

#### `query`

```
df.query('Column2 != Column4')

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

---

#### `np.vectorize`

```
import operator
f = pd.np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x != y)
df[f(df['Column2'], df['Column4'])]

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

...Just for fun.

---

#### List Comprehension

```
df[[x != y for x, y in zip(df['Column2'], df['Column4'])]]

  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

Faster than you think!

Comment: `df.loc[lambda x : x['Column2']!=x['Column4']]
`

Comment: @W-B Nice one, forgot loc supports callbacks!

Comment: Does `pd.np.vectorize(operator.ne)` have any benefit over just `operator.ne`? In fact, won't the former work row-wise, which is probably not what you want?

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the great answer! In my dataframe 'column2' is of type int64, while 'column4' is an object. For some reason your answer isn't removing duplicate values between these two columns.

Comment: @jpp You're right, it does not. I moved the answers around a bit and replaced `ne` with a `lambda` (...just for fun!).

Comment: @sg123 If `column4` is an object, try this: `df['column4'] = pd.to_numeric(d['column4'], errors='coerce')` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942854/4909087) for more information.

Comment: @sg123, see my updated answer where `df[df.Column2.ne(df.Column4)]` looks to be simplest one.

Comment: @pygo ne is just the operator equivalent of !=, Same as this. Actually in terms of simplicity I would argue for query.

Comment: @coldspeed, You are correct its just a wrapper over Arithmetic operations API ,However, query method under the hood passed to `DataFrame.loc` and if that fails because of a multidimensional key (e.g., a DataFrame) then the result will be passed to `DataFrame.__getitem__()`. BUt Good to see multiple way of doing it.

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to pass a list of ff columns instead of explicitly calling out df['Column2'], df['Column4']? I have a use case where I need to compare where about 9 column rows match and then drop them if they do.

Comment: @JoeRivera you could change `zip(df['Column2'], df['Column4'])` to `df[list_of_cols].values.tolist()`.

Comment: @cs95 I received this error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
`test_df = final_df[[x != y for x, y in final_df[is_updated_cols].values.tolist()]]`

Comment: @JoeRivera it's too much to explain in a comment but essentially you will need the same number of variables as columns you are slicing on. I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I can't advise further. I suggest to open a question.

Comment: @cs95 here is a solution provided by @jezreal `L = ['S','T'] df = df[df[L].ne(df[L[0]], axis=0).any(axis=1)]` in case anyone else is looking to pass a list of column names to match.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way around:

Solution with masking the matched values..

```
>>> mask = (df.Column2 == df.Column4)
>>> df[~mask]
  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

Or simply using `Boolean indexing` ...

```
>>> df[ df.Column2 != df.Column4 ]
  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

another one with `DataFrame.drop` method:

```
>>> df.drop(df[(df.Column2) == (df.Column4)].index)
  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

In addition to above one, if you want to make changes directly into the dataFrame, use `inplace=True`:

```
df.drop(df[(df.Column2) == (df.Column4)].index, inplace=True)
```

Another Nice solution with [pandas.DataFrame.ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) Wrapper for flexible comparison methods ne.

```
>>> df[df.Column2.ne(df.Column4)]
  Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4
0     Pat      123    John      456
1     Pat      123    John      345
3   Larry      678   James      983
```

Comment: Hmm, check this again? This isn't exactly a duplicate dropping problem.

Comment: @coldspeed, let me reproduce  & check