# Python: How to remove rows where multiple columns have equal values?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove rows where multiple columns have the same values. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009788/remove-rows-where-value-in-one-column-equals-value-in-another) about two columns and tried to extend to multiple columns, however I get an error.

Here is some sample data, similar to my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['table1',10,8,7],['table2',3,3,3],['table3',3,8,11],['table4',12,12,12],['table5',13,15,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['table_name','Attr1','Attr2','Attr3'])
```

and my desired result

```
res = [['table1',10,8,7],['table3',3,8,11],['table5',13,15,5]]
result = pd.DataFrame(res,columns=['table_name','Attr1','Attr2','Attr3'])
```

I tried

```
[df[df['Attr1'] != df['Attr2'] | df['Attr1'] != df['Attr3'] | df['Attr2'] != df['Attr3']]]
```

which retrieves the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for compare all values by `Attr1` column and test if at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].ne(df['Attr1'], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
  table_name  Attr1  Attr2  Attr3
0     table1     10      8      7
2     table3      3      8     11
4     table5     13     15      5
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].ne(df['Attr1'], axis=0))
   Attr1  Attr2  Attr3
0  False   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False   True   True
3  False  False  False
4  False   True   True

print (df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].ne(df['Attr1'], axis=0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Another solution is test number of unique values by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df = df[df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].nunique(axis=1).ne(1)]
```

Comment: This works only if `Attr1` is one of the duplicates. Consider the case where Attr1-3  is `[10, 8, 8]` ?

Comment: @ChrisA - Then is possible use `df = df[df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].nunique(axis=1).ne(2)]`

Comment: @ChrisA - So you think get rows if all values are unique? Like `df = df[df[['Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']].nunique(axis=1).eq(3)]` ?

Comment: That should do it yeah

Answer (score 3):

Use df.query:

```
df = df.query("Attr1 != Attr2 != Attr3")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create conditions for each and then perform your comparison:

```
c1 = df['Attr1'].ne(df['Attr2'])
c2 = df['Attr1'].ne(df['Attr3'])
c3 = df['Attr2'].ne(df['Attr3'])
>>> df[c1 | c2 | c3]
  table_name  Attr1  Attr2  Attr3
0     table1     10      8      7
2     table3      3      8     11
4     table5     13     15      5
```

Each condition will be a series indicating whether or not the inequality holds, e.g.

```
>>> c1
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

>>> c1 | c2 | c3
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Boolean index with the condition being that the number of unique values across axis 1, must be equal to the width of the `DataFrame`:

```
df = df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(df.shape[1])]
```