# Dropping rows in pandas if column values are duplicated in more than 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, drop

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951558/remove-rows-that-two-columns-have-the-same-values-by-pandas) is almost what I need, but I cannot adapt it for my needs.

I have a df with a lot of columns, where the last 8 columns are columns with means scores.

**Example**

```
  Column1 Column2  Mean1  Mean2  Mean3  Mean4  Mean5  Mean6  Mean7  Mean8
0       A       X     50     50     50     50     50     50     50     50
1       B       Y     20     21     22     23     24     25     26     27
2       C       Z     50     50     50     63     99     54     24     12
3       D       F     40     41     42     43     44     45     46     47
```

**Reprex**

```
{'Column1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, 'Column2': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z', 3: 'F'}, 'Mean1': {0: 50, 1: 20, 2: 50, 3: 40}, 'Mean2': {0: 50, 1: 21, 2: 50, 3: 41}, 'Mean3': {0: 50, 1: 22, 2: 50, 3: 42}, 'Mean4': {0: 50, 1: 23, 2: 63, 3: 43}, 'Mean5': {0: 50, 1: 24, 2: 99, 3: 44}, 'Mean6': {0: 50, 1: 25, 2: 54, 3: 45}, 'Mean7': {0: 50, 1: 26, 2: 24, 3: 46}, 'Mean8': {0: 50, 1: 27, 2: 12, 3: 47}}
```

I want to drop all rows in the dataframe, if 3 or more columns in 8 mean columns have the same value.

**Expected output** (first and third rows were dropped, having value 50 three and more times)

```
  Column1 Column2  Mean1  Mean2  Mean3  Mean4  Mean5  Mean6  Mean7  Mean8
1       B       Y     20     21     22     23     24     25     26     27
3       D       F     40     41     42     43     44     45     46     47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = list()
for number in df.T.columns.tolist():
    if df.T.groupby(number).size().max()>=3:
        n.append(number)
df.drop(n)
```

Comment: Perfect, now I need to apply it to my huge dataframe. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if I want to remove duplicates only in these 8 columns and do not touch other 200 columns (even with duplicates), I must do the following code:. Going through my 8 columns only and then applying it to the whole dataframe. 
`n = list()
for number in df.iloc[: , 220:228].T.columns.tolist():
    if df.iloc[: , 220:228].T.groupby(number).size().max()>=3:
        n.append(number)`# Drop        
`foo = df.drop(n)`

Comment: Firstly create a new dataframe  df_new = df.iloc[:,220:228]  and apply code to df_new and get  n . Finally run df.drop(n).

Comment: Works perfectly, you are the best, thank you so much!